# Why is String considered Abstract data type?

Tags: java

Was checking lectures from this link :-

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/

It states Strings as ADT, I am confused why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are confusing the general, programming-language-independent term "Abstract Data Type", and the Java-specific term "abstract class".

An Abstract Data Type is ... as described on the page you link to:

> An abstract data type is a data type whose internal representation is hidden from the client.

A Java "abstract" class is a class that has the `abstract` keyword in its class declaration.  That means that you cannot make an instance of it.

These are two different ideas: two different meanings of the word "abstract".

---

So in the case of `String`:

- It is an ADT because the internal representation is hidden.
- It is NOT an `abstract` class: `new String("42")` works for example.

Answer (score 0):

its an abstract data type or simple abstract data type , as it fulfill the basic definition of abstract type i.e. , we don't know how it implemented or created but we can use  operations defined for it . ( not knowing the implementation , directly use the operations attached to the data type is simple definition of abstract data types)